# How to implode this pattern to array?

Tags: php, arrays, regex, implode

I want implode this txt pattern to Multidimensional Arrays and echo array into table

**My pattern :**

```
<group1&john,www.johnsite.com]jack,www.jacksite.com]jorge,www.jorgesite.com^group2&Ivan,www.ivansite.com]Dan,www.dansite.com]Ted,wwww.tedsite.com^
```

I want echo this pattern like this (dont show website address):

Group1: john-jack-jorge
Group2: Ivan-Dan-Ted

Comment: Using a standardized format would make this a lot easier...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$str = "group1&john,www.johnsite.com]jack,www.jacksite.com]jorge,www.jorgesite.com^group2&Ivan,www.ivansite.com]Dan,www.dansite.com]Ted,wwww.tedsite.com^";

$str = trim($str, "^");
$groups = explode("^", $str);

foreach($groups as $val){
    $group = ucfirst(explode("&", $val)[0]);
    $arr = explode("]", explode("&", $val)[1]);
    $name = array();
    foreach($arr as $v)
        $name[] = explode(",", $v)[0];
    $name = implode("-", $name);
    echo $group.": ".$name."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: tnx its works now how can i validate html form? i want users cannot use this character   &],

Comment: use Jquery validation for that , disabling the character entries input.

Comment: can you help me again? :X